# A regex that would find all comments, python

Tags: python, regex, comments

I am writing a compiler (for a practice language) in python and I want to split my text to tokens by spaces or comments. I tried `/\*.*?\*/|/{2}.*?\n|\s` : the fisr regex pattern is supposed to fine comments in the form of `/** text */` or `/* text */`, possibly multyline. The second regex is supposed to fine comments in the form of `// text` that ends with the new line character. The last one finds white spaces.

My question:

I checked my regex [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/examplesprogrammer.html) and it seemes to be great, but when I call

```
temp = file.read()

temp = temp.split('/\*.*?\*/|\/{2}.*?\n|\s',flags=DOTALL)

print temp
```

it returns a list with only one elements which is the entire text I'm parsing.

Any ideas about where am I going wrong? Thanks!

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't the 2nd regex be `\/{2}.*\n` instead of `/\{2}.*\n`?

Comment: But that's how it is right now...

Comment: In the second regex, you escape the forward slash. Is that a typo?

Comment: @Vikas: why are you escaping `/` ?

Comment: @yotamoo, Yeah, looks like you edited the typo.

Comment: I did, so its supposed to fine now right?

Comment: @JoelCornett, that is how it was there in original question before OP edited it. I wanted to point out the typo.

Comment: I doesn't work even when I remove the back slash...

Answer (score 3):

Problem is not with regex but with `split`. You are calling [`split` method of an `str`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.split), which does not split by regex. It splits string by a sub-string. Instead use [`re.split`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.split)

```
>>> code = open('file').read()
>>> code
'/* comment */\ntext1\n// comment\n\ntest2\n\ntext3 // comment\n\ntext4 /* comment */\n'
>>> import re
>>> re.split
<function split at 0x10d9c6320>
>>> re.split('/\*.*?\*/|\/{2}.*?\n|\s', code)
['', '', 'text1', '', '', 'test2', '', 'text3', '', '', 'text4', '', '', '']
```

[More information on python re module](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html).

Comment: Ok this is great, thanks. Still a little problem - the list I get now includes a lot of empty elements like
['', '', '', '', '', class, main] and so on

Comment: @yotamoo, filter those out. `[i for i in re.split('/\*.*?\*/|\/{2}.*?\n|\s', code) if i]`